# Configurar rotas usando areas em ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

Estou tentando configurar uma rota usando area da seguinte maneira:

**No RouteConfig.cs**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
    }
}
```

Criei uma area chamada "Adm" e no **AdmAreaRegistration.cs** está da seguinte forma:

```
public class AdmAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "Adm";
        }
    }
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Adm_default1",
            "Adm/{controller}/{action}/{id}-{descricao}",
            new {controller = "EntradaDeUniformes", action = "Exibir"}
        );
        context.MapRoute(
            "Adm_default",
            "Adm/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**EntradaDeUniformesController.cs** que está dentro da pasta Adm/Controllers

```
    public ActionResult Exibir(int? id, string descricao)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        EntradaDeUniforme entradaDeUniforme = db.EntradaDeUniformes.Find(id);
        if (entradaDeUniforme == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(entradaDeUniforme);
    }
```

Mas quando eu tento passar:

```
http://localhost/escola/Adm/EntradaDeUniformes/Exibir/1-Calça-Azul
```

Retorna este erro: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou fazendo algo de errado ou falta alguma coisa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como eu configurei a rota dessa forma `"Adm/{controller}/{action}/{id}-{descricao}"`

Quando eu passava `http://localhost/escola/Adm/EntradaDeUniformes/Exibir/1-Calça-Azul`

Não funcionava porque o "Azul" era entendido como outro parâmetro por causa do "-".

Então fiz de outra forma no  **AdmAreaRegistration.cs**:

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Adm_default1",
            "Adm/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{descricao}",
            new {controller = "EntradaDeUniformes", action = "Exibir"}
        );
```

Passando:

```
http://localhost/escola/Adm/EntradaDeUniformes/Exibir/1/Calça-Azul
```

Que funciona perfeitamente!